# Javascript code for auto-advance on matrix format in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, matrix, qualtrics

I'm creating a survey on Qualtrics where I'm hoping to auto-advance to the next page after the survey taker makes his/her choice on the last question of a matrix. 
I have the javascript code to auto-advance after a click on a single-choice question but I need to edit it to auto-advance on the click of the last single-choice question in a matrix table:

```
var that = this;
this.questionclick = function(event,element){
    if (element.type == 'radio')  {
       that.clickNextButton();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done programmatically by using two more methods from the API; getChoices() and getSelectedChoices(). This allows us to write flexible code that will work regardless of the order in which the choices are selected or how many options are presented.

```
var that = this;
var choices = this.getChoices( "radio" ).length;
this.questionclick = function( event, element ){
    var selected = that.getSelectedChoices().length;
    if ( choices  == selected )  {
       that.clickNextButton();
    }
}
```

We compare the number of choices with the number of answers and only progress once each statement has been answered.

Comment: Instead of using `var that = this` you should either use the arrow operator, `=>`, if ES6 is available, or [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: Good tip. I was following the syntax from the Qualtrics API documentation. I'll read up on the link you posted.